# Temporarily cache RUN apt-get update && apt-get install in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to temporarily cache this line `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y` in `Dockerfile`?

Reason is when troubleshooting `Dockerfile`, I rebuild the image several times and this line has the longest wait time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it possible.

Create docker image from your docker file. Separate file to 2 Dockerfile's, first with `FROM` and `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y`, second with other instructions

> cd /dir/with/Dockerfile

> docker image build -t my-fast-docker .

After build use image in second Dockerfile

> FROM my-fast-docker:latest

Comment: You know what I feel like I actually know it's just this simple but here we are. Thank you!

Comment: @IMB I'm glad I was able to help! Enjoy!